# Как захостить telegram бота на сайте pythonanywhere? | python, telebot

Tags: python, telebot, telegram, pythonanywhere

Подскажите пошагово пожалуйста, как захостить бота с нуля на сайте pythonanywhere?

Answer (score 0):

Переходим на сайт https://www.pythonanywhere.com/ регистрируемся переходим на почту которую указали подтверждаем email нажав на ссылку убрав все галочки и нажав сохранить. Переходим обратно нажимаем `files ->Browse files -> Upload a file` загружаем файл .py бота. Переходим обратно на Dashboard `New console -> $Bash` появляется терминал с помощью команды pip установите необходимые библиотеки (`pip3 install --user telebot`). После вводим
`python название_скрипта_который_загрузили.py` всё бот запущен проверяем. Во вкладке Tasks можно запланировать запуск команды ежедневно. Для того чтобы бот работал без перерыва нужно купить платную подписку и добавить это во вкладке Tasks. Иначе бот будет отключатся.

Comment: думаю стоило предупредить, что через пару часов бот уснет

Comment: @ClarkDevlin Исправил